# STS(Spring Tool Suite) Output Console view changed suddenly

Tags: spring-tool-suite

[Spring tool's default console view changed suddenly, click in the link to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbwwT.png)

[my console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z5gI.png)

Comment: what exactly changed suddenly?

Comment: click on my console view you will see funny characters appearing

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the screenshot it looks to me like Spring is configured to produce ANSI-colored console output, whereas the console view does not display them correctly, even though the ANSI coloring feature of the console seems to be enabled. Not sure exactly why this doesn't work correctly, but you can switch back to non-ANSI coloring output in the launch config of your Spring app.